# How I upload Image on server in jpg or png format in Titanium (Android)?

Tags: php, android, titanium

I want to upload image to server for my phone gallery.

I have done with iOS device this is working well. But, in Android Device have problem.

I take image from my Device gallery and post on server. This is upload successfully.
after this i see on Server.

whose Image uploaded by Android device, this is in .txt format. (iOS have working well).

How i remove the problem.Please help me i show you my coding structure.

```
 Ti.API.info("success! event: " + JSON.stringify(event));
        var image = event.media;

        var abc = event.media.imageAsResized(400 , 400);


        Ti.API.info(abc.height +" x "+ abc.width);
        alert(abc.height +" x "+ abc.width);

       var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

        xhr.onerror = function(e)
        {
            Ti.API.info('IN ERROR ' + e.error);
            alert("error");
        };
        xhr.onload = function()
        {
            Ti.API.info('IN ONLOAD ' + this.status + ' readyState ' + xhr.responseText);
            alert("IN ONLOAD " + this.status + " readyState " + this.readyState + "re " +xhr.responseText);

        };


         xhr.open('POST','http://reviewprototypes.com/kishan/filetest.php');
        xhr.send({file:abc});
 },
                cancel : function() {

                    alert("Cancel Library ");
                },
                error : function(error) {

                    alert("Error Massage "+error);
                },
                allowImageEditing:true,

               });
```

Any suggestion is appreciated..
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We had several issues while uploading binary data with Android so we decided to convert everything using base64 and do the same on the server side. Problem here is maybe the http client of android and handling binary files in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my problem from this reference [Example](https://gist.github.com/furi2/1378595). Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the POST requests content-type header to `Content-type: multipart/form-data`, other than that I can't really suggest anything :(

Dom

Answer (score -1):

try **https** :
 xhr.open('POST','**https**://reviewprototypes.com/kishan/filetest.php');

Snowmed.